# List of files installed from apt package

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dpkg

How do I get a list of files that were or will-be installed when I apt-get a package?  Conversely, can I find what package(s) caused a particular file to be installed?

Comment: Similar on SU http://superuser.com/questions/82923/how-to-list-files-of-a-debian-package-without-install on Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package

Comment: Both ubuntu and debian have web for this, for example https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/tldr/filelist

Answer (score 237, accepted):

**Note:** in the following commands, a command beginning with 'root#' means it needs to be run as root.

To find which files were installed by a package, use `dpkg -L`:

```
$ dpkg -L $package
```

`apt-file` can tell you which files will be installed by a package before installing it:

```
root# apt-get install apt-file
root# apt-file update
$ apt-file list $package
```

Or if you have the package as a `.deb` file locally already, you can run `dpkg` on it:

```
$ dpkg --contents $package.deb
```

To find which package provides a file that is already on your system, use:

```
$ dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

To find which package provides a file that is not currently on your system, use `apt-file` again:

```
$ apt-file search /path/to/file
```

Comment: Keep in mind that while this will get you most of what you need it will not give you everything.  Several packages create configuration files as part of their setup scripts.  These files will not be reported by dpkg.

Comment: `$ dpkg -L package` not `$ dpkg -L $package` putting the $ in front of the package names returns an error

Comment: The dollar is meant to be understood as a variable, meaning you need to replace `$package` with the actual name of the package.

Comment: conffiles of a package (if any) are listed by command `dpkg --status $package`. For the reverse operation use `grep $filename /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.conffiles`.

Comment: bit late Q - - what does `sudo apt-file update` do ??

Comment: @samshers, `apt-file update` command populates the db which `apt-file` uses for searches.

Comment: what if you don't have apt-file?

Comment: @confiq if you don't have apt-file, run `sudo apt-get -y install apt-file` then run `sudo apt-file update`. After that you can use the tool as described above.

Comment: I find `apt-file list $package` the most useful. `dpkg -L $package` lists directories. Thanks!

Comment: I still think my answer is the best because it never has to download anything to disk, but that is just me being biased :p

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that should do it for you without the need to downloading the package to disk.  This solution also doesn't require any third party programs (like apt-file) or anything outside of a minimum debian/ubuntu install.

```bash
# Function that gets the package layout of a remote package from 
# apt/apt-get/aptitude/synaptic/etc...
apt_list () 
{
    # Build array of packages 
    local packages=("$@");
    # Iterate package indexes up to the length of the array minus 1
    for pkg in $(seq 0 1 $((${#packages[@]}-1)));
    do
        # Pretty little separator in case you are examining the 
        # contents of multiple packages.
        echo -e "\n#### ${packages[$pkg]} ####\n";
        # Pipe steps (in order)
        # Print the url to the .deb package remote location from sources.list
        # delimit by single quotes and select only the url
        # pipe the url to xargs after a curl silent follow redirects 
        # insecure (no cert checking some may wish to take the -k off 
        # the curl command.
        # use dpkg -c to check the contents of the downloaded package in stdin
        # Use perl to remove dots after modification timestamp on sysroot
        apt-get download -o Dir::Cache::archives="./" --print-uris ${packages[$pkg]}\
        | awk -F\' '{print $2}' | xargs -I '{}' curl -skL '{}' |\
         dpkg-deb -c /dev/stdin | perl -ne 's,(:\d\d )[.]/,$1/,g;print';
        # Line break so the last package name doesn't wind up on same line as PS1
        echo;
    # end loop
    done
}
```

Then use `apt_list <package name1> [package name 2]`

e.g.
`apt_list curl wget`

In regard to your second question you can use `dpkg -S /path/to/isntalled/file` or if you are trying to view the contents of an already downloaded/local .deb file with `dpkg --contents </path/to/deb/file>`. As for reverse checking files from packages where you don't know the name of the package that owns said file, a third party solution [apt-file](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file) (a software package that indexes the contents of packages in your available repositories and allows you to search for a particular file among all available packages), is available.  This is like ***`yum provides`*** on rhel based systems like CentOS) would be the best bet.

​​​​​​

Answer (score 4):

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file/in/question
```

As far as I'm concerned, dpkg is the low-level tool that apt-get depends on.

Comment: Yes, dpkg is the command that adds and removes software and files from you mcomputer. apt (incl. Apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, etc.) is the programme that calls dpkg

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed `dlocate`, you can use `dlocate -L` the same way as `dpkg -L`. It works exactly the same in this case, but has a number of other options.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for those of you who using Linux Mint:

```
apt content <packageName>
```

Comment: `E: Invalid operation content`

Comment: hm, it works on my system. what apt version do you use? you can check apt version with 'apt show apt' command. mine is 2.4.10

Comment: `apt --version` gives `apt 2.4.10 (amd64)`. I don't see `content` documented anywhere. Do you have `apt` aliased to anything? (`type -a apt`)

Comment: `22:14:~$ type -a apt
apt is /usr/local/bin/apt
apt is /usr/bin/apt
apt is /bin/apt`

Comment: hm...

22:23:~$ which apt
/usr/local/bin/apt
22:23:~$ file /usr/local/bin/apt
/usr/local/bin/apt: Python script, ASCII text executable

Comment: 22:24:~$ apt show apt
Package: apt
Version: 2.4.11
Priority: important
Build-Essential: yes
Section: admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: APT Development Team <deity@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 4 240 kB

Comment: Example of apt content output:


`22:25:~$ apt content apt
/.
/etc
/etc/apt
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-vendor-ubuntu
/etc/apt/auth.conf.d
/etc/apt/keyrings
/etc/apt/preferences.d`

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint btw:

`22:28:~$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria`

Comment: `content` must be a feature of that python script you have in `/usr/local/bin`, I guess

Comment: Looks like it is. I just found this:
https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/cmdline/apt.cc

APT is an util written in C++.
I kind of pissed by how deeply Python is integrated in Ubuntu and its derivatives. You can't use any of those distributives without installing Python. Is Debian also tied that much with Python or any other JIT or scripting language except Bash and C++?

Comment: I fixed my answer.
What distributive do you use, A Davis?

Comment: 23:39:/usr/local/bin$ apt contains /usr/local/bin/apt 
mintsystem: /usr/local/bin/apt

yep, Q.E.D.

btw, 'contains' is another example of a Mint addition to the apt tool.

Comment: Interesting -- good to know about these minty additions to apt.

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-file` command needs to download a database that can be 100's of MB and take several minutes. If you're only interested in one or two packages, it's quicker to download the deb file(s) and view the contents using standard tools.

```bash
# change to a directory where you have write permission
cd /tmp

# download the package's .deb file, e.g. for dbab
apt download dbab

# print the files that will be installed by the package
dpkg -c dbab_1.5.8-1_all.deb
```

Furthermore, you can extract the control files from the package, and see what the scripts will do on installation or removal. Particularly, the post-install script may be of interest.

```bash
# this will extract the control files to a new dir, ctrl-files
dpkg -e dbab_1.5.8-1_all.deb ctrl-files

# then they can be viewed, e.g.
more ctrl-files/postinst
```