# Where is phpmyadmin installed when apt-get install is used

Tags: ubuntu

Where is the phpmyadmin installed when I run `apt-get install phpmyadmin`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dpkg -L phpmyadmin` to list the files installed by the package.

Comment: I want to move the phpmyadmin to /var/www which is the apache web root folder

Comment: Why? The phpmyadmin Ubuntu package comes with a proper apache2 vhost configuration.

Now if you really want to put everything in /var/www, maybe you should install it manually instead of using a package.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to track down all details with this article,
[**How To Manage Packages Using apt-get, apt-cache, apt-file and dpkg** Commands](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/debian-ubuntu-install-upgrade-remove-packages-using-apt-get-apt-cache-apt-file-dpkg/)
(With 13 Practical Examples).

There is also a similar question here,
[List of files installed from apt package](https://serverfault.com/questions/96964/list-of-files-installed-from-apt-package).

You might find these pages useful,

- [phpMyAdmin Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin)
- [Apache phpMyAdmin Installation & Configuration](https://cwiki.apache.org/VCL/phpmyadmin-installation-configuration.html), and
  [How To Set Up A Ubuntu/Debian LAMP Server](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server)