# apt-get installed

Tags: apt

how to get a list of all installed packages from apt-get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of files installed from apt package](http://serverfault.com/questions/96964/list-of-files-installed-from-apt-package)

Comment: @Dennis - I think there's a subtle difference, once is a list of files, one is a list of packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg --get-selections` will output a list.  Bonus: you can input that list into `dpkg --set-selections` to copy those selections.

Comment: There's also `dpkg -l` which will show you the status of every package on the system, the version and a description of the package.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` itself cannot do this, but you can use `dpkg --list` or `aptitude search ~i` to see a list of installed packages.

Answer (score -1):

If you specifically care about packages installed via apt-get, rather than packages installed via any mechanism (e.g. apt-get, aptitude, dpkg, dselect), look in */var/log/apt/history.log*.

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` and `dpkg -l` will show the status of every package present, regardless of what utility was used to install it.

Comment: Packages installed via aptitude also use that log.